# I can't get button name to appear on gui or input to be saved when clicking on button using PySimpleGui

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I am using PySimpleGUI and I want to be able to click on a Button and have that show up on the text under the button as the selection. The options are to split or data populate but I am unable to figure out how to make the event handler update the text or to save that option and then have the code act accordingly based on that option.

The code so far looks a little like this

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
          [sg.Text('Would you like to SPLIT or SPLIT AND DATA POPULATE')],
          [sg.Button('Split', key='-SPLIT-'), sg.Button('Split and Populate', key ='-SANDP-')],
          [sg.Text('Current Process:'), sg.Text('Process', key='-PROCESS-')]
         ]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout,size=(1000,500))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == 'EXIT':
        break
    if event == '-SPLIT-':
        window['-PROCESS-'].update(values("-SPLIT-"))
        choice1 = window['-PROCESS-'].update("split")
    if event == '-Split and Populate-':
        window['-PROCESS-'].update("Split and Populate")
        choice2 = window['-PROCESS-'].update("Split and Populate")
window.close()

#psuedo code following
if choice1
    bla bla bla
if choice2
    bla bla bla
```

I want to be able to click and have that button name be stored in choice1 or choice 2 and also have that button name appear in the gui, is this posible?

Answer (score 0):

The key will be the `button_text` of `sg.Button` if option `key` or `k` not specified and not duplicate, so there's no event for '-Split and Populate-'.

Most of time, the value of a `sg.Button` won't changed, so it won't be data in `values` from `sg.Window().read`. To get text on `sg.Button`, you can call method `get_text` of `sg.Button`.

For event generated from the key of element when you click on `sg.Button` or other element, then decide what to do in `if ... elif ... else ...` statement.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Would you like to SPLIT or SPLIT AND DATA POPULATE')],
    [sg.Button('Split', key='-SPLIT-'),
     sg.Button('Split and Populate', key ='-SANDP-')],
    [sg.Text('Current Process:'),
     sg.Text('Process', size=(0, 1), key='-PROCESS-')]
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(1000,500))

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event is None or event == 'EXIT':
        break

    elif event in ('-SPLIT-', '-SANDP-'):
        window['-PROCESS-'].update(value=window[event].get_text())
        if event == '-SPLIT-':
            pass
        elif event == '-SANDP-':
            pass

window.close()
```